# Evaluating an improper integral containin exp and sqrt

Tags: integration

Is it true that $\int_0^\infty  y^{-1/2}e^{-\lambda y}dy=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\lambda}}$? I'm not sure if the integral exists for all $\lambda$ or is the value correct. It looks hard for me to evaluate it.

Comment: The substitution $y=u^2$ turns this into the [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Gamma Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) is defined by

$$\Gamma(z)=\int_0^\infty y^{z-1}e^{-y}\,dy$$

and $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt{\pi}$.

For $\lambda >0$ in our integral of interest, enforcing the substitution  $\lambda y=x$ gives immediately

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty y^{-1/2}e^{-\lambda y}\,dy&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\Gamma(1/2)\\\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\lambda}}
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Answer (score 1):

$$
I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{{e}^{-\lambda y}}{\sqrt y} dy
$$

Setting $y=x^2$, $dy = 2xdx$ we get:

$$
I =  \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{{e}^{-\lambda x^2}}{x} 2x dx\\
I = 2\int_{0}^{\infty} {e}^{-\lambda x^2} dx 
$$

Set now, $u = x\sqrt{\lambda}$, $du = \sqrt{\lambda}dx$:

$$
I = 2\int_{0}^{\infty} {e}^{-u^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}}du
$$

And note the famous gaussian integral:

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} {e}^{-u^2} du = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}
$$

You get:

$$I = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\lambda}}$$

As mentionned in the comments [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#Computation) are several ways of computing the gaussian integral.

Comment: And of course, one might ask "how does one evaluate the "Gaussian Integral?"  [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#Computation) are several approaches.  Of course, we can save all of this development by simply using the Gamma Function.

Comment: +1 for being direct, though